# 'schoolmanamgement.MainForm' does not contain a constructor that takes 7 arguments

Tags: c#

I want to take these values to the next form with parameters

```
public void password()      
{           
    if (txtusername.Text=="admin" && txtpass.Text=="admin")
    {
        int saveid=1,printid=1,deleteid=1,updateid=1,searchid=1;
        String ww="myschool";
        String role="admin";

        MainForm Form=new 
        MainForm(printid,saveid,searchid,updateid,deleteid,ww,role);

        Form.ShowDialog();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the constructors of `MainForm` - it doesn't have any that takes 7 arguments

Comment: Also as you are new to StackOverflow please check the How To Ask page and take the Tour so to see how to post questions in the required way in StackOverflow

Comment: As the exception says your MainForm does not have a constructor which takes 7 arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a contructor with 7 arguments into your MainForm class...